# $http post not working after migration from angularJS 1.3-beta to 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

I am migrating my project from angularjs 1.3 beta to 1.4 , '$http get' is working fine but **'$http post'** is creating problem.
Below is  user authentication code which works fine in 1.3 but not working in 1.4

```
factory.authenticate = function (email, password) {
    var payload = {
        email: email,
        password: password
    };
    var rid = Security.reqKey();
    payload['rid'] = rid;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Base_url +'service/auth',
        param: {
            rid:  rid
        },
        data: $.param(payload),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
};
```

After migration to 1.4 it produce error:

> POST http://localhost/ 405 (Not Allowed)  XHR failed loading: POST

*(which was working fine earlier)*

there is a case in which this code give desired result .
If I put debugger in chrome browser and run whole code by pressing f10.

Comment: what is `Security` and why it is not injected? Also it looks like this function `Security.reqKey()` is asynchronous and that is why it is not in time when you execute your code without debugger and it is on time when you debug it - it is simply the question of couple milliseconds.

Comment: Security is nothing but a client side factory  whose value is base on  Date.now().valueOf(); I don't think this is creating problem. Since I have tried this code with out param parameter . but it is producing same error. :(

Comment: so that is probably a problem, that you don't pass the parameter. Your error is anyway a server-side-kind. You must have a look there first what is the source of a problem (although I am pretty sure this is because you don't have this rid parameter). You won't get a solution here if you don't post all related functions including the server side things.

Comment: As suggested by you , I have checked my code and value of `var rid = Security.reqKey();` ( rid = 1444659515802) get resolved before $http get called.

Comment: Have you changed anything on your server?

Comment: No , I have changed nothing on server. :(

Comment: Maybe you should check the server side and find out why it's returning a 405

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http),

> params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET
>   parameters.

`param` should be `params` and therefore your data is not being serialized, which would explain why the server is rejecting your POST (since post requires more privileges than GET presumably).

But even this may be incorrect, as I think `params` is for GET only (but maybe it works for both).

You also don't need jquery `$.param()` $http has a built in serializer. `data` can just set to `payload`.